# HotChocolate apply UseFiltering for a field along with Resolver in QueryType

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I have an issue with using resolver with UseFiltering() method in query type.

At the moment, I'm using resolver for all fields in Query type. I don't know if this is best practice or not. I'm going to illustrate scratch codes.

```
public class QueryType {
    // nothing here just a empty class
}

public class QueryTypeWithFieldResolvers : ObjectType<QueryType>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<QueryType> descriptor)
    {
        base.Configure(descriptor);

        descriptor.Field(nameof(GenericResolvers<User>.Get))
                  .Name("get")
                  .Type<ListType<ObjectType<User>>>()
                  .ResolveWith<GenericResolvers<User>>(r => r.Get(default!));

        descriptor.Field(nameof(GenericResolvers<User>.GetById))
                  .Name("getById")
                  .Argument("id", argsDescriptor => argsDescriptor.Type<StringType>()
                  .Type<ObjectType<User>>()
                  .ResolveWith<GenericResolvers<User>>(r => r.GetById(default!, default!));
    }
}
```

Everything above is still working as normal. Until I want to add **Filtering** and with this approach using **Resolver** for new field named **"filter"** in query type.

It seems like **the Filtering middleware** is not working as expected, it returns all data from database.

```
public class QueryTypeWithFieldResolvers : ObjectType<QueryType>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<QueryType> descriptor)
    {
        // omitted
        ...

        descriptor.Field(nameof(GenericResolvers<User>.Filter))
                  .Name("filter")
                  .Type<ListType<ObjectType<User>>>>()
                  .ResolveWith<GenericResolvers<User>>(r => r.Filter(default!))
                  .UseFiltering<UserFilterInputType>();
    }
}
```

#### **Update to declare field **"filter"** as method in QueryType class**

With this approach then it WORKS by following instruction from [Hotchocolate Filtering](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/fetching-data/filtering/)

```
public class QueryType {
    public IQueryable<User> Filter([Service] IGenericRepository<User> repo)
    {
        return repo.Query();
    }
}

public class QueryTypeWithFieldResolvers : ObjectType<QueryType>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<QueryType> descriptor)
    {
        // omitted
        ...
        
        // updated to use field expression directly
        descriptor.Field(f => f.Filter(default!))
                  .Type<ListType<ObjectType<User>>>()
                  .UseFiltering();
    }
}
```

As I know, they are both valid code-first approach of HotChocolate, but I don't know what differences between two approachs above. So please help me to explain why guys? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UserFilterInputType : FilterInputType<UserInput>
{
    protected override void Configure(IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<UserInput> descriptor)
    {
    }
}

public class UserInputType : InputObjectType<UserInput>
{
    protected override void Configure(IInputObjectTypeDescriptor<UserInput> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(t => t.Id).Type<StringType>().Name("id");
        descriptor.Field(t => t.Username).Type<StringType>().Name("userName");
}

public class UserInput
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

This was my mistake because of using generic `UseFiltering<T>()`. And the  constraint was `FilterInputType<UserInput>`, it must be `FilterInputType<User>`. Because we are manipulating on data of domain class **User** not input class

So that why it leads to issue not working in the Filtering middleware.
All I need to do is to change constraint of FilterInputType from **UserInput** to **User**

```
public class UserFilterInputType : FilterInputType<User>
{
    protected override void Configure(IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<User> descriptor)
    {
    }
}
```